# What are the different ways of writing xml values in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I am new to .xml files in general and I am currently working on project where I take simple .txt file with values inside of it and generating a .xml file out of it.

I am trying to replicate this in the xml file:
`<value1 name="value2"/>`
Only value2 gets changed based on the .txt file.

Using

```
xmlWriter.WriteStartElement()
```

with

```
xmlWriter.WriteElementString()
```

I am getting working files but the resulting .xml file looks different from what I want.

`<value1 name="value2"> </value1>`

Comment: The closing tag in xml the tag name is optional.  So the two outputs are equivalent and the c# library is giving the optional tag name.

Comment: `<value1 name="value2"></value1>` and `<value1 name="value2"/>` are equivalent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
xmlWriter.writeStartElement("value1");
xmlWriter.writeAttributeString("name", "value2");
xmlWriter.writeEndElement();
```

also set:

```
XmlWriterSettings wSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
wSettings.Indent = true;
wSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
wSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
```